# Instagram Real-time PHP API

Tags: php, real-time, instagram

got some questions about the Instagram real-time api. first let me tell you what I want to do. I'd like to run a daemon process with a socket connection or something of the like to the Instagram API to get a constant feed of photos with a certain tag. We estimate it to be a large amount of data at a particular time (thus why we want to go Real-time). This process will parse the feed and store it into a mongodb.

Secondly, for the front end, I'd like to display all new, live photos in real-time, possible with ajax or some form of checking on a set interval.

Problem being, I can't find anyone doing this with php. All of the resources I have seen use Node.js and Tornado. Has anyone done this with PHP or know of a good Real-time API demonstration/tutorial to get me started?

Here's the documentation...
http://instagr.am/developer/realtime/